# chrome- multiple websites in single tab

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible programmatically in chrome open multiple web pages in single tab? It could be fine for different type of aggregators.

Eg. I little look at chrome http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html  but I don't find API for this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using a content-script to add your iframes to a page, I don't think there is specialized API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I try iframes, but some sites(eg. facebook,..) doesn't run in iframes. 
Do you know some workaround for including content from this "problematic" sites which don't allow iframes ?